# jQuery: Loading iframe on click - how to write manageable code?

Tags: jquery, iframe

looking for some feedback / advice from advanced web devs on how to actually write manageable code for this scenario.

**Scenario**

We have various links on the site in  containers. Upon clicking one of these, we use jQuery to create an iframe and load a page in it.

**HTML part:** (starting after body)

```
    <a id="slot1" href="#0">Text</a>
    <a id="slot2" href="#0">Text</a>
    <a id="slot3" href="#0">Text</a>
    <a id="slot4" href="#0">Text</a>

    <!-- iframe content will be displayed within this div -->
    <div id="content">
    </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
    <script>
    $("#slot1").click(function(){$("#content").html('<iframe src="http://www.google.de/">');});
    $("#slot2").click(function(){$("#content").html('<iframe src="http://www.google.com/">');});
    $("#slot3").click(function(){$("#content").html('<iframe src="http://www.google.co.uk/">');});
    $("#slot4").click(function(){$("#content").html('<iframe src="http://www.google.ru/">');});
    </script>
```

Now this gets tedious and redundant if the list grows (think of #slot57 !). How to write it more flexible and elegant?

So far I thought of targeting all slot IDs $('[id^="slot"]') and slicing the index(4) in order to get the actual clicked number. But then how to load the right iframe content!?

I'm stuck. Any thoughts / advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are able to do some markup modification then you can try to do this in the markup:

```
<a id="slot1" href="#google.de/">Text</a>
<a id="slot2" href="#google.com/">Text</a>
<a id="slot3" href="#google.co.uk/">Text</a>
<a id="slot4" href="#google.ru/">Text</a>
```

then you can use this jQuery code:

```
$('a[id^="slot"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the jump of anchor
    $("#content").html('<iframe src="http://www.'+ $(this).attr('href').slice(1) +'">');
});
```

---

or a better one if you are using **html5** then use `data-*` attribute to serve the url:

```
<a id="slot1" href="#0" data-url="http://www.google.de/">Text</a>
<a id="slot2" href="#0" data-url="http://www.google.com/">Text</a>
<a id="slot3" href="#0" data-url="http://www.google.co.uk/">Text</a>
<a id="slot4" href="#0" data-url="http://www.google.ru/">Text</a>
```

then you can use this jQuery code:

```
$('a[id^="slot"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the jump of anchor
    $("#content").html('<iframe src="http://www.'+ $(this).data('url') +'">');
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6Q9J/)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try This

**HTML**

```
<a class='slots' href="http://www.google.de/">Text1</a>
    <a class='slots'href="http://www.google.com/">Text2</a>
    <a class='slots'  href="http://www.google.uk/">Text3</a>
    <a  class='slots' href="http://www.google.ru/">Text4</a>

    <!-- iframe content will be displayed within this div -->
    <div id="content">
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
  $('a').click(function(e){
   $("#content").html('<iframe src='+$(this).attr('href')+'>');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Acuv/1/)**