# Load on Click Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page with several different iframes which are delaying my loading time so I'd like them to load only when I click on a separate button.

As I have it set up now, there are "window blocks" and inside each one of these divs there are two siblings, the "app link" and the app "window";

so here's my structure (there are several similar "window blocks" on the same page)

```
<div class="w-clearfix window-block">
<a class="app-link w-inline-block" data-ix="open-window" href="#" style="transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;">
<div class="w-clearfix wapps window ui-draggable" data-ix="collapse-on-load" style="transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s; opacity: 0; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(100%) translateZ(6000px); display: none;">
```

I'm also using a little jquery to make the windows draggable (it's a very similar situation to a Windows (or MacOS) desktop: shortcuts and windows.

```
$( function() {
    $( ".window" ).draggable({ handle: ".window-handle" });  
} );
```

Is it possible to make each sibling window load as I click on the button next to it with a single "line" of code? Or do I have to add one for each class / element? What's that line of code? (I'm sorry if this sounds dumb..)

Is it possible to also unload that div on a second click and then reload again when the button is clicked (for a third time)?

I'm also trying to make each window jump to the top of the screen (move up on Z?) as I click on each window but that's not working, any suggestions?

Thank you very much...

Comment: You mean you want to load a iframe into a div when a button is clicked? I dont see a button in your code.

Comment: First line talks about `iframe` and the html has `div` - which is it?

Comment: hey, sorry for that, what I would really need is to load a whole div (and its content and iframe) only on click; in this case the "app link" is the button and "w apps" is the window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Loading iframe on click - how to write manageable code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757785/jquery-loading-iframe-on-click-how-to-write-manageable-code)

Comment: You could create the iframes with empty `src` values, and then use a button to trigger a function like `document.GetElementById('IframeID').src="link"` to actually load the iframe. Unfortunately, you'd have to do that for each frame separately.

Comment: Thanks guys, @Rob, I think that's what I'm looking for. in this case the slots would be my buttons and content would be the divs to be loaded, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is AJAX. A button click sends a request to the server and writes the response HTML into the window. The [W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) is pretty straightforward.